# Foreground service notification takes a few seconds to appear/show up

Tags: android, service, notifications, foreground

Foreground service notification shows too slowly on Android 12. Used `ContextCompat.startForegroundService(...)` and `mContext.startForegroundService(...)`. It still shows in 5-10 seconds.

Here is an example of my code:

```
private void createNotificationChannel() {
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
      NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, "Counting steps", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
      channel.enableVibration(false);
      channel.setSound(null, null);
      channel.setShowBadge(false);
      notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
  }
}
```

The onStartCommand method:

```
  @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

      String input = intent.getStringExtra("numberOfSteps");
        createNotificationChannel();

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
          0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
      Notification.Builder notificationBuilder = new Notification.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
        .setContentTitle("Counting steps")
        .setContentText(input)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_directions_walk_24)
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);


      startForeground(FOREGROUND_ID, notificationBuilder.build());
    }

        return START_STICKY;
    }
```

How can I start or show a foreground service notification quickly?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Services that show a notification immediately

> If a foreground service has at least one of the following
> characteristics, the system shows the associated notification
> immediately after the service starts, even on devices that run Android
> 12 or higher:
>
> The service is associated with a notification that includes action
> buttons.
>
> The service has a foregroundServiceType of
> mediaPlayback, mediaProjection, or phoneCall.
>
> The service
> provides a use case related to phone calls, navigation, or media
> playback, as defined in the notification's category
> attribute.
>
> The service has opted out of the behavior
> change by passing FOREGROUND_SERVICE_IMMEDIATE into
> setForegroundServiceBehavior() when setting up the
> notification.
>
> On Android 13 (API level 33) or higher, if the user denies the
> notification permission, they still see notices related to foreground
> services in the Foreground Services (FGS) Task Manager but don't see
> them in the notification drawer.

See: [Services that show a notification immediately](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services#notification-immediate)

Java example code:

```
Notification.Builder notificationBuilder = new Notification.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
          .setContentTitle("Counting steps")
          .setContentText(message)
          .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.your_cool_icon)
          .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
          notificationBuilder.setForegroundServiceBehavior(Notification.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_IMMEDIATE);
        }
```

Kotlin example:

```
val notificationBuilder: Notification.Builder =
            Notification.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setContentTitle("Notification title")
                .setContentText("Content title")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.your_cool_icon)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
            notificationBuilder.setForegroundServiceBehavior(Notification.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_IMMEDIATE)
        }
```